# How to create a collection of various datatypes in UIpath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

in UiPath RPA, how can I create a collection variable with different datatypes? For example, a collection of strings, numbers, booleans or even arrays or lists. Tried to look in System.Collections.Generic, but couldn't find the relevant one.

Appreciate your Support
Hara

Answer (score 1):

Create a new variable. Select `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` for the type, then select your custom class. Here's a collection custom objects.

[image: list of excel cells]

Alternatively, use an `Array<T>`, and then pick your custom class. The following image shows a string array:

[image: string array]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of Objects by creating a new variable with type `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Object>`. The `Object` class is the root class of the .NET type hierarchy, so the List can hold almost anything.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a Dictionary String/Object :

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/inSuQ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFsiS.png)